# Can I change value's decimal point seperately in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, decimal-point

I want each values of df have different decimal point like this

```
        year   month   day 
count   1234   5678    9101
mean    12.12  34.34   2.3456 
std     12.12  3.456   7.789
```

I searched to find a way to change specific value's decimal point
but couldn't find the way. So this is what I've got

```
        year        month       day 
count   1234.0000   5678.0000   9101.0000
mean    12.1200     34.3400     2.3456 
std     12.1200     3.4560      7.7890
```

I know the round() method but I don't know how to assign it to each values not the whole row or columns.
Is it possible to change values separately?

Answer (score 0):

You can change displayning of floats:

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,6f}'.format

#if necessary convert to floats
df = df.astype(float)
```

Or change format to 6 zeros:

```
df = df.astype(float).applymap('{:.6f}'.format)
```

Comment: thank you for a quick reply
but how do I assign a single value in this code?
what does : means?

Comment: @JasmineC - `how do I assign a single value in this code` ? There is no assign, not understand.

Answer (score 0):

The `format` approach is correct, but I think what you are looking for is this:

Input file `data.txt`

```
        year        month       day 
count   1234.0000   5678.0000   9101.0000
mean    12.1200     34.3400     2.3456 
std     12.1200     3.4560      7.7890
```

Formatting (see [formatting mini language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language))

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

file = "/path/to/data.txt"
df = pd.read_csv(file, delim_whitespace=True)

# update all columns with data type number
# use the "n" format
df.update(df.select_dtypes(include=np.number).applymap('{:n}'.format))
print(df)
```

Output

```
        year  month     day
count   1234   5678    9101
mean   12.12  34.34  2.3456
std    12.12  3.456   7.789
```